# Is 東西二つ idiomatic?

Tags: definitions, idioms, phrases

I came across this sentence about a traditional festival in Japan:

> 阿月の神明祭は、阿月地区を東西二つに分けて行われる災厄除けや病気除け、豊作を祈願して行われる。

([link](http://www.pref.yamaguchi.lg.jp/cms/a50400/cul-pro/atsuki.html))

The general meaning is clear, but what I don't fully understand is this part: `東西二つに分けて`

Its seems to me that `東西二つ` is idiomatic for "all over" (judging from what I saw of a Google search of the phrase...I couldn't find a definition of them together), but the I couldn't figure out what `に分けて` means in this context? I know could mean "separated" (分かる, to separate), but apparently in the て-form it can also mean "particularly" or "above all", which makes even less sense to me..."particularly East and West?"

Comment: Is it not just "separated into two parts, East and West"?

Comment: Lol I totally agree

Comment: Well, this may be a case of over-thinking ^.^ I couldn't figure out how you could separate East from West, I didn't think about city sections...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`阿月地区を東西二つに分けて` means "separate the Azuki district into two parts, east and west".

You could insert a の, making it `東西の二つ`, but the adverbial use without it is not uncommon for these "listing"-jukugo like `東西`, `優劣`, `大小` etc.

Answer (score 6):

東西二つに分けて just means *east and west separated in two*.

> 分ける：to separate/devide
>
> 東西: east and west

The festival will take place in the sectors of Azuki separated in two, east and west.